# Pronunciation of "I live with my family"

Tags: грамматика, перевод, произношение

About the sentence: "Я живy с семьёй." --> Phonetic: [Yah zhivu s sem'yoy.]

When pronouncing the "independent c". Would you pronounce both the "s:es" in one go or would you make a short pause before pronouncing "sem'yoy"?

Answer (score 1):

No, it usually goes like "double S". Actually, you may/should even omit a pause after "*живу*", and say "SS" by using the exhalation of "*У*".

Answer (score 1):

You would pronounce them in one go. Think of *give u**s s**ome*.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination

Note also that in this case, you've got two phonemically different consonants; the first [s] is hard and the second one is soft ([sʲ]). Some people assimilate, though, making them both soft; it's subject to free variation.

Russian generally doesn't do pauses. The only Russian word that contains a "pause" of sorts (glottal stop) is the colloquial **не-а** "nope".

Answer (score 0):

No pause, just make it doubled, as it is.  Pronounce it as if imitating a snake's hissing.